# How to create <h1/> element that uses React Material User Interface theme?

Tags: html, css, reactjs, material-ui

I've set the theme to `dark` and would like to have an `h1` element use that theme. How is this done?

The following doesn't work:

```
<MuiThemeProvider theme={theme}>
  <h1>Page Title</h1>
...
```

The following works but emits a warning:

```
<MuiThemeProvider theme={theme}>
  <DialogTitle><h1>Page Title</h1></DialogTitle>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<MuiThemeProvider theme={theme}>
  <Typography variant="h1">Page Title</Typography>
...
```